# MVC4 jQuery unobtrusive validation of Min value

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, unobtrusive-validation

I have a custom `MinAttribute` I want to use to validate that user input is greater than a given value.

I have been able in implement it server-side, but am unable to make it work client-side using unobtrusive validation.

My Model:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "{0} is Required.")]
[Display(Name = "Total")]
[Min(25, ErrorMessage = "You need to enter at least 25")]
[DataType(DataType.Currency)]
public Decimal Total{ get; set; }
```

MinAttribute.cs:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class MinAttribute : ValidationAttribute, IClientValidatable
{
    private decimal MinValue { get; set; }

    public MinAttribute(int minValue)
    {
        MinValue = minValue;
    }
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (value != null)
        {
            if (value is decimal)
            {
                if ((decimal)value >= MinValue)
                {
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public override string FormatErrorMessage(string name)
    {
        if (this.ErrorMessage.IsNullOrEmpty())
            return string.Format("{0} must be greater than or equal to {1}", name, MinValue);
        else
            return this.ErrorMessage;
    }

    protected override ValidationResult IsValid(object value, ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        if (IsValid(value))
        {
            return ValidationResult.Success;
        }
        else
        {
            var errorMsg = FormatErrorMessage(validationContext.DisplayName);
            return new ValidationResult(errorMsg);
        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<ModelClientValidationRule> GetClientValidationRules(ModelMetadata metadata, ControllerContext context)
    {
        yield return new ModelClientValidationRule
        {
            ErrorMessage = this.ErrorMessage,
            ValidationType = "min"
        };
    }

}
```

Where I am stuck is I am unsure how exactly the jQuery should look. I have tried:

```
$.validator.addMethod("min", function (value, element) {
        return value > 25;
    });
```

and

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("min", function (options) {
        options.messages["min"] = options.message;
    });
```

But have not been able to get it working correctly..

Is there something I am obviously doing wrong?

The outputted html from the view includes all necessary `data-` attributes:

```
<input class="input text valid" data-val="true" data-val-min="You need to enter at least 25" data-val-number="The field Total must be a number." data-val-required="Total is Required." id="Total" maxlength="7" name="Total" style="width:125px;" type="tel" value="0">
```

so it must be something wrong with the jQuery implementation.
I have included the appropriate references to the js files as unobtrusive validation is working on other fields..

Thanks.

I am also open to ideas for better ways to implement this. I did not use range, as I would like to have a different error message for min and max not a generic "must be between X and Y"
I did also attempt to use `validator.unobtrusive.adapters.addMinMax()` but could not find any detailed documentation on how to use it and was unable to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at jquery.validate.unobtrusive(.min).js, you'll see:

```
adapters.addMinMax("length", "minlength", "maxlength", "rangelength").addMinMax("range", "min", "max", "range");
```

In other words, there's already an adapter named "min".  Have you tried using a different name?

Comment: I changed all `Min`s to `Mini` so model attribute was `Mini` class was `MiniAttribute` updated JS to use `mini` but still doing the same thing. no chrome console errors, just not validating client-side.

Comment: Actually, the existing adapters are named "length" and "range", and the range adapter uses "min" and "max" attributes to define the allowable range.

Comment: Rule out the obvious: make sure the input element is in a form, and set its type to text.

Comment: I have checked the inputs and changed it from `tel` type to text, re tried all the combinations of the  above, but still not working. Surely there is an easier way to validate a min/max value clientside..